# Summarise with first value

Tags: r, segmentation-fault, dplyr

I encountered strange behaviors while using `summarise`.

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 4),
                 color = c(NA, "blue", "red", "blue", NA),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df
#   id color
# 1  1  <NA>
# 2  2  blue
# 3  3   red
# 4  3  blue
# 5  4  <NA>
```

### First part

Let's extract the first value of `color` for each `id`:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(result = color[1])
# # A tibble: 4 × 2
#      id result
#   <dbl>  <chr>
# 1     1       
# 2     2   blue
# 3     3    red
# 4     4   <NA>
```

I expected `<NA>` instead of the empty string. Did I do something wrong? `first(color)` produces the right output, but I believed that `color[1]` was equivalent.

Moreover, `color %>% first` produces the same output as `color[1]`, and that gets me even more confused.

### Second part

Let's type the following nonsensical code:

```
df%>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(color = color[1],
            color2 = first(color))
```

I get a segfault. Is this a known bug or should I report it? I found some old SO questions and GitHub threads looking quite similar, but they look solved.

**Note**: I use `dplyr 0.5.0` on `R 3.3.3`

Comment: I'm using the dev version, and the first bug is fixed, but not the second. The second is particular to the order, though, so I suspect its related to grabbing the version of `color` calculated as the previous parameter of `summarise` instead of the variable from the data.frame passed in. Check [the issues](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues) and if you don't see a similar one, add it.

Comment: I get NA instead of blank with the devel version and is the same output as `first`

Comment: @alistaire: Thanks. There are similar issues but all of them are closed, so I created a new one here: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2673

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments: both issues were bugs, and both are fixed in dplyr 0.7.0